# Can I point multiple domain names to single DNS?

Tags: domain, nameserver

Is it possible to have different domain names point to a single domain server? Something like:
name1bob.com point to ns1.server123.com and 
name2ted.com point to ns1.server123.com

Answer (score 3):

Yes. "*Random filler to meet the minimum character requirement*"

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can host [multiple zones](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DNS_zone) for [multiple domains](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain_Name_System#The_domain_name_space) on a single server.  [Representation of your domain has nothing to do with the domain of the computer that hosts your dns](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b1/Domain_name_space.svg).